# tkinter.insert to print values in next column

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, treeview

I am having a dataframe with 6 columns, what i need from tkinter is to print data in next column everytime when first loop iterate. For eg:

```
xls = pd.read_excel(file)
df = pd.DataFrame(xls)

df_col = df.columns.values

tree["columns"]=(df_col)
counter = len(df)

for x in range(len(df_col)):
    tree.column(x, width=100 )
    tree.heading(x, text=df_col[x])
    for i in range(counter):
        tree.insert("" , 0, values=(df[df_col[x]][i]))
```

**Desired Output:**
[image]

**What im getting from my above code is:**
[image]

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Doesn't `tree.insert("" , 0, values=(df[df_col[x]][i]))` need to be `tree.insert("" , counter, values=(df[df_col[x]][i]))`? Just guessing though, I don't have an easy setup I can try this...

Comment: thanks for your response but this isn't working for me.

Comment: @JonClements my code is iterating but it is printing all the results in one column, i want it to print it to next column everytime when first loop iterates.